# Why does PHP return the first value of an array when referencing said array as an object property?

Tags: php, xml, object

Why does the second echo line in the following code return (*string*) 'first' rather than an array?

Code:

```
<?php

$foo = simplexml_load_string(<<<EOF
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<document>
    <body>
        <content>first</content>
        <content>second</content>
    </body>
</document>
EOF
);

echo '<pre>$foo entire object:', "\n", print_r($foo, true), "\n";
echo '$foo->body->content: ', "\n", $foo->body->content;

?>
```

Result:

```
$foo entire object:
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [body] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [content] => Array
                (
                    [0] => first
                    [1] => second
                )
        )
)

$foo->body->content: 
first
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a general PHP feature.  Try:

```
class Foo
{
    public function Foo()
    {
    $this->a = array("foo", "bar");
    }
}
$f = new Foo();
print_r($f->a);
```

It's a feature of SimpleXML that accessing a property like that gets the first applicable child, which can then be converted to a string.

Though SimpleXML is an extension, you could implement something similar in pure PHP using the [_*get*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) and [_toString](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring) magic methods.

Comment: That's what I suspected, any link to docs? I wouldn't know where to look in the [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) docs.

Comment: Good edit (the __get magic method).
How does example 2 relate though? The plot property contains just a string.

Comment: @cainmi, the only difference is there's just one `plot` in the XML.  You can make the example identical to your situation by using `echo $xml->movie[0]->rating;` (on the same sample XML).  Note that there are two ratings, and this outputs the first one.